# Connecting to two identical bluetooth speakers at the same time

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, audio, bluetooth, speakers

I own two JBL Flip Speakers.

They both are able to pair individually via Bluetooth and perform well. When I attempt to make them perform at the same time via the Audio/Midi Setup tool on my Mac (aggregate device), only one seems to be able to be connected a time, and the speakers will drop connection, and the other will pick it up.

My thought is that OSX cannot sustain two simultaneous Bluetooth audio connections with the same type of device. When switched to the aggregate device,  it plays out of one device, dropping the connection to the second. At some predefined interval, the second device reconnects with OSX, and OSX switches the input to that speaker.

Regardless of theories, how would one go about resolving this?

Image for reference:

[image]

Comment: In the event someone comes across this thread and thinks I've found the solution: I haven't.

Answer (score 5):

I am currently running two Bluetooth speakers together at the same time via my MacBook Pro 15" (early 2013). I connected them together on the Bluetooth menu like you and went to the Audio MIDI Setup. I made a new multi output device with the two speakers and it works perefectly with no delay. The volume keys on the keyboard does not work as the stay on full but everything else does work.

The [Jabra Solemate Mini Wireless Speaker](http://www.jabra.com/products/speakers/jabra_solemate_mini/jabra_solemate_mini) and the [Sony SRS BTX500](http://www.sony.com/electronics/wireless-speakers-docks/t/wireless-speakers) are the two speakers.

Comment: Edit your question to include a **link** to your image and someone with sufficient reputation will insert it for you.

Comment: This doesn't address the concern of two of the exact same speaker.

Comment: This works, you can change the name of the speakers from the bluetooth system preferences just right click on one of the devices and select rename.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Miccus Mini‑Jack TX4](http://www.miccus.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=MMJTX-04) transmitter and splitter to send Bluetooth signals from my iPad to 2 separate Marshall Stanmore speakers and the sound is outstanding!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an android device.   It would connect to one, then the other, but not both.   The problem for me, ended up being solved by discovering that android had a separate "dual audio" setting which needed to be turned on.    After that it still took me 2 or 3 tries with a pair of JBL clip 2's, but suddenly it took.   (I probably should have just re-booted... bet that was the problem).    I know I'm android and you're asking about an Ios device, but there's a good chance there's a similar issue for you... a separate setting that needs to be enabled.